# Editing different types of vocabulary in attribute table of shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table

I wanted to edit the name of the cities in the attribute table of a shapefile, for example for Turkey, there have cities like 'Eskişehir' and 'İzmir', How I can edit these names exactly the same in qgis?

I've copy-pasted the name for the city in Portugal 'A Coruña' was working (copy-pasted from Wikipedia), but for these cities of turkey weren't.

Is anyone knows how to edit them in qgis attribute table?

Comment: @BERA Yes correct, is in shapefile

Comment: What happens when you try with the Turkish names?

Comment: @BERA Either not shows or just with normal 's' ('Eskişehir'), for the city "Erbil" --> I have to type it as 'Hewlêr', then doesn't even appear on the map.

Comment: Did you try to change "Layer properties > General > Data source encoding" to "UTF-8"? And then, copy-paste.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz Yes, I've changed it from "System" to "UTF-8", but nothing changed.

Comment: A Coruña is in Spain (not in Portugal) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is going wrong with inputing a special character in the attibute table, but I cannot reproduce your error. It is working properly even without changing the character encoding. I use `Data Source Encoding "System"`

Here is the workfow:

- open tha attribute table
- Select the points that you want to update their names
- I copied the first name `Eskişehir` in your example
- Pasted the first name `Eskişehir` and pressed enter
- Repeat the last two steps for the second name `İzmir`.

Here is the output under the modified field in the image below:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help, i will try it soon :) best regars, ndr